# Google API return invalid_grant in production but not in local

Tags: python, google-api, google-play-services

I have a very strange exception using google API in python. The goal is to check on server side the validity of a token corresponding to an in-app subscription from an Android application.

So to do that, we have a service account attached to our Google Play account and we try to authentify our request using oauth through the p12 key (converted into a pem certificate in order to remove the pass phrase):

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

with open("googleplay.pem") as f:
    private_key = f.read()
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL, private_key, scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'])
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
client = build('androidpublisher', 'v2', http=http_auth)
```

And this works perfectly on my computer. But the last line triggers an exception on my servers: invalid_grant

I don't understand where does that could come from! If you can help we with that, it would we marvelous!

some additional code I used to convert the p12 certificate to a pem certificate:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in privatekey.p12 -nodes -nocerts > privatekey.pem
```

Then I removed the first 4 lines.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue.

I fixed it by syncing the system time using [NTP](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html)

This will only work on a root server. Not on a virtual server.
Contact your server hosting provider if you rent a vServer.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late validation of your answer but this was actually the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help giving you any clue.

I have recently fixed an problem with similar error message (also contains "invalid_grant"). My case was due to an absent of refresh_token value in the OAuth2 credentials that leads to failed credentials refresh. So my fix was to get new refresh token from google. It turns out google only distribute refresh the first time a user authorize with google. Unless the user disconnects the app and reauthorize. Or in the app, `flow.params['approval_prompt'] = 'force'` is set (usually for local debugging).

My case is about credentials for web application and OAuth2 authorization. Yours looks like a service account, so I am not sure if your problem is a refresh problem, too.

Comment: Hum thanks but I don't think this is relevant for my case… Indeed, I'm using a service account so I should not have this issue. :(